# How to fix video flickering around a movie played with mplayer on frame buffer?

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, mplayer

I'm running a qt embedded application and mplayer, both of them on framebuffer.

When I start video playing through mplayer, I get a lot of flickers around the movie.

See the following movie:

http://youtu.be/kbKpfjLHzTY

How to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Qt4.7.4 qwith QWS. Your instruction doesn't fix the issue. Probably the source of the problem is related to other thing.

Comment: I think you might not have understood my comment, so I left an answer.  I am pretty sure that this is your issue; I had the same issue and I have viewed your video.  You can also just loop `fbv` or something else and see the same thing happen.  I think some *QWidget* in you screen is periodically re-drawing.  As `mplayer` is drawing at approx 30x/sec you get a flash as it and Qt redraw.  You might give *video size* parameters to `mplayer` and it may also solve your issue.  You can use `fbdump` to capture screen shots, or something like `dd if=/dev/fb0 of=test.scr bs=480 count=320`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Qt 4** with **QWS**,the embedded linux graphics sub-system for writing directly to a *frame buffer* you can run the following in a the  **-qws** server's GUI thread *before* invoking `mplayer`,

```
QWSServer *server = QWSServer::instance(); 
if(server) 
   server->enablePainting(false); // Suspend Qt's drawing.
```

You can use a *SIGCHLD* or something to figure out when `mplayer` is finished and *re-anble* painting.  Another way would be to position `mplayer's` output window and use a [QWSEmbedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwsembedwidget.html) to tell **Qt** not to draw there.

Both **QWS** and `mplayer` open the *frame buffer* and draw to it directly.  There is nothing to marshal access to the display device.  The **QWS** sub-system allows multiple *Qt* application to draw to the screen at the same time.  However, it has no control over other processes accessing the *frame buffer*.  For this reason, **X11** or other display managers like [**Wayland**](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/architecture.html), etc can be used.  This is generally the method use in **Qt5**.